# Javascript post to PHP and get back an array?

Tags: php, javascript

So i have this piece of javascript, it posts to `foo.php` with value `val`, gets back `data`, empties the container and call function `graph` which will fill the container with a new chart.

```
$.post("foo.php", {val: val}, function(data){
    if(data.length >0) {
        $('#container').html('');
        graph(data);
    } 
});
```

in `foo.php`, how do I make it pass back an array instead of string? at the moment I just have an `echo` in `foo.php` that echos the data delimited by a comma, ie: `1,2,3,4,5`. then in the `graph` function I have a `split(',' data)`  that creates an array for later use.

I mean, all this works fine, I'm just wondering if I can avoid the split step and have `foo.php` return an array directly.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is for:

```php
echo json_encode( $array );
```

---

Just remember to [set JSON headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file), so that jQuery will know to parse the returned data as JSON. If you don't, you'll have to specify that in your jQuery AJAX call as follows:

```js
$.post("foo.php", {val: val}, function(data){
    if (data.length > 0) {
        $('#container').html('');
        graph(data);
    } 
}, 'json'); // <-- Here you're specifying that it'll return JSON
```

Answer (score 3):

**[json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)** your array in PHP and jquery can easily parse your JSON encoded data.